# Cleaning Data in R

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr

I have a dataset which looks something like the following-

```
Date     Customer      Cost      Location
1/2/15    Jon          $50       Sunnyvale, CA
1/5/15    Jon          $125      Sunnyvale, CA
1/15/15   Jon          $25       Sunnyvale, CA
1/3/15    Martha       $30       Fresno, CA
1/7/15    Martha       $40       Fresno, CA
2/16/15   James        $30       Tempe, AR
2/20/15   James        $70       Tempe, AR
```

I want to convert into the following format, where each row gives me information regarding a single customer, his latest arrival date, net spend, total occurrences and creates an arrival model-

```
Date     Customer     Mean ITA(days)    Frequency    Cost    Location
1/15/15    Jon        6.5                3          $200     Sunnyvale, CA
1/7/15     Martha     4                  2          $70      Fresno, CA
2/20/15    James      4                  2          $100     Tempe, AR
```

Any help doing it in R is appreciated. I am using the tidyr package but am not able to figure out how to get this done.

Comment: What is ITA? How do you count it?

Comment: First, learn how to convert dates, then learn how to use dplyr, in particular its `summarise` command. (Pretty sure `ITA = ( last(Date) - first(Date) ) / n()` in case anyone's confused by it)

Comment: Generally, with `dplyr` you'll need `df %>% group_by(Customer, Location) %>% summarise( ... )`, where `...` is the arguments to construct all the columns you want. First, get your original data clean; your dates are not date objects, and your costs are not numbers if they have a `$`. Let us know when you get stuck, and we'll point you in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

As alistaire pointed out, you need dplyr, not tidyr, for this.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  group_by(Customer) %>% 
  summarise(Frequency = n(), 
            Cost = sum(Cost),
            ITA = (max(Date) - min(Date))/2,
            Date = max(Date))
```

> ```
>   Customer Frequency  Cost      ITA       Date
>     (fctr)     (int) (dbl)   (dfft)     (date)
> 1    James         2   100 2.0 days 2015-02-20
> 2      Jon         3   200 6.5 days 2015-01-15
> 3   Martha         2    70 2.0 days 2015-01-07
> ```